# using scss with lit custom elements?

Tags: sass, rollup, lit

Just wondering if [rollup-plugin-scss-lit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-scss-lit) is still the best way to use scss files with lit custom html elements.  The last I saw were SO posts from 2022 or so, nothing on the lit site when searching for scss.